# Edit/Update collections in EF Core: from DTO or repository?

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-core, automapper, .net-5, ef-core-5.0

I have the following classes: `Company`, `Country`, `Person`.

```
class Country
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public Person President { get; set; }
    ICollection<Company> Companies { get; set; }
    ICollection<Person> People { get; set; }
}
class Company 
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Code { get; set; }
    public Country Country { get; set; }
    ICollection<Person> People { get; set; }
}
class Person
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
}
```

I have the following DTO(ViewModel) classes: `CompanyDTO`, `CountryDTO`, `PersonDTO`:

```
class CountryDTO
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string PresidentName { get; set; }
    int[] CompaniesIds { get; set; }
    int[] PeopleIds { get; set; }
    string[] PeopleNames { get; set; }
}
class CompanyDTO
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Code { get; set; }
    public string CountryName { get; set; }
    int[] PeopleIds { get; set; }
    string[] PeopleNames { get; set; }
}
class PersonDTO
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
}
```

I use AutoMapper, so I do

```
CreateMap<Company, CompanyDTO>()
    .ForMember(p => p.CountryName, o => o.MapFrom(p => p.Country.Name))
    .ForMember(p => p.PeopleIds, o => o.MapFrom(p => p.People.Select(s => s.Id).ToArray()))
    .ForMember(p => p.PeopleNames, o => o.MapFrom(p => p.People.Select(s => s.Name).ToArray()))
    .ReverseMap();
```

I use in EntityFramework (Core) repository "normal"(business) classes, like `Country`; and I use in Views only the DTO's as models like `CountryDTO`.

The problem come when updating the existing collections.

It is not clear, how to create the business object that will be updated: **from repository** or **from the DTO** (ViewModel). If we take from DTO, the EF will (try to) duplicate the children collections. NOK.

If we take from repository, we should manually update field by field all the object properties, so the mapping like is not usefull at all.

```
/// CompaniesController
/// Saving a Company being in edit mode
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<IActionResult> Edit(int id, CompanyDTO companyDto)
{
    if (id != companyDto.Id) { return NotFound(); }

    if (ModelState.IsValid) {
        try {
            
            //
            // 1) How to get the edited country 
            //        a) from repository or 
            //        b) from the mapper?
            //
            var spec = new CompanyWithPeopleSpecification(id);
            var company = await _repository.SingleOrDefaultAsync(spec);
            // or
            var company = _mapper.Map<Company>(companyDto);

            //
            // 2) How to update the changed People's collection?
            //
            
            //
            // if we got from _repository, we should 
            //

            // a) update all value fields from DTO
            company.Code = companyDto.Code;
            company.Name = companyDto.Name;
            
            // b) filter the collection items to remove and to add
            var existingPeopleIds = company.People.Select(x => x.Id).ToList();
            var peopleIdsToRemove = existingPeopleIds.Except(companyDto.PeopleIds).ToArray();
            var peopleIdsToAdd = companyDto.PeopleIds.Except(existingPeopleIds).ToArray();

            foreach (var personId in peopleIdsToRemove)
                company.People.Remove(company.People.Single(s => s.Id == personId));                    

            var specPeopleToAdd = new PeopleFromIdsSpecification(peopleIdsToAdd);
            var peopleToAdd = await _repository.ListAsync(specPeopleToAdd);
            foreach (var person in peopleToAdd)
                company.People.Add(person);

                            
            //
            // if we got from _mapper, we should 
            //

            // a) update all object fields from repository              
            company.Country = _repository.GetById<Country>(companyDto.CountryId)
            
            // b) the added to collection exising in DB objects will be duplicated
            foreach(var personId in companyDto.PeopleIds)
                company.People.Add(_repository.GetById<Person>(personId));
            
            await _repository.UpdateAsync(company);
        }
        catch (DbUpdateConcurrencyException) {
            if (!CompanyExists(companyDto.Id)) {
                return NotFound();
            }
            else { throw; }
        }
        return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
    }

    ViewData["Countries"] = new SelectList(_repository.List<Country>(), "Id", "Name", companyDto.CountryId);
    ViewData["AvailablePeople"] = new MultiSelectList(_repository.List<Person>(), 
                                                                        "Id", "Name", companyDto.PeopleIds);

    return View(companyDto);
}
```

Comment: What repository? DbContext is already a Unit-of-Work, DbSet is already a Repository. The rest of the question is unclear as well - you can use AutoMapper to map from API DTOs to database DTOs. You aren't restricted to mapping only one way. If you want to update or create new database rows based on API DTOs, map the DTOs to EF entities and persist them. If you use the POST and PUT methods appropriatelly, you'll already know whether the DTOs are for new or updated objects. If not, you should have different actions for create/update

Comment: I have two sources from witch a business object could be created: from (DbContext == Repository == Database), using repository object, OR from the View (= from DTO, using the mapper object).

Comment: I have `CountryDTO` in view, I save in DB the `Country` object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From Repository.

For the first part of the question, Automapper has a `Map` call that can copy values across to an existing entity.

```
var company = await _repository.SingleAsync(spec);
mapper.Map(companyDto, company);
```

`ReverseMap` should take care of getting the details back into the entity, though it won't do things like add/remove associated entities. For that, your implementation for Ids to Add/Remove is consistent with the approach I use.

When it comes to updating data and associations, it is generally advisable to split up the operations as atomically as possible; For example to have operations to add or remove country associations rather than having the client alter an entire Company object graph then submit the changes via a method like "UpdateCompany".  An all-or-one update operation can involve a fair bit of work, so I'd reserve it for where it is absolutely needed.

Comment: I added an extension method as "answer" to this question, maybe it would be useful if you use `IdEntity` like objects...

Comment: the Map(source, destination) I ddin't use till now! I will test it! thanks a lot!

Comment: Yeah, while Automapper's documentation is generally pretty useful, details about the specific methods can be a bit buried. I was trying to find a link to official doco for the `Map<src,dest>` and couldn't find one to link into the answer!   :)

Answer (score 0):

After the Steve recommendation, I built a extension method that would update any existing collection from repository to an array of ids:

```
public static class BusinessExtensions
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Updates a business objects collection (usually from repository) 
    /// to correspond to the given list of ID's (usually updated in the View)
    /// </summary>
    /// <typeparam name="T">Any entity having an Id (IdEntity)</typeparam>
    /// <param name="collectionToUpdate">reposotory collection to be updated</param>
    /// <param name="updatedIds">list of new id's to syncronise with the repository collection</param>
    /// <param name="Spec">function transforming a list of ids into a list of business objects from repository</param>
    public static void SyncCollection<T>(this ICollection<T> collectionToUpdate, int[] updatedIds, Func<int[], IEnumerable<T>> Spec)
        where T : IdEntity
    {
        var existingEntityIds = collectionToUpdate.Select(x => x.Id).ToList();
        var entityIdsToRemove = existingEntityIds.Except(updatedIds).ToArray();
        var entityIdsToAdd = updatedIds.Except(existingEntityIds).ToArray();
        var entitiesToRemove = Spec(entityIdsToRemove);
        var entitiesToAdd = Spec(entityIdsToAdd);

        foreach (var entity in entitiesToRemove)
            collectionToUpdate.Remove(entity);
        foreach (var entity in entitiesToAdd)
            collectionToUpdate.Add(entity);
    }
}
```

Usage in a controller

```
var spec = new CompanyWithPeopleSpecification(id);
var company = await _repository.SingleOrDefaultAsync(spec);

_mapper.Map(comapnyDto, company;

company.People.SyncCollection(companyDto.PeopleIds, 
    ids => _repository.List(new PeopleFromIdsSpecification(ids)));
```